# MC33063 heating problem

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, heat

I'm using a MC33063 to generate a -9V supply to power 7 TL084's. I'm using a 7805 regulator to power the 33063 circuit. However, the IC and the regulator heats up a lot -- I burned one IC due to that. This might be due to loading -- since the heating is minimal in case I power one IC with it. Are there any solutions to avoid this problem?

The circuit used is same as the one given in the  [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/product/MC33063A/datasheet/application_and_implementation#SLLS6369101). I've used it previously to power the IC's, but I'm unsure what's the problem is now.

[image]

Comment: What load current are you taking and precisely what are the components chosen such as the flyback diode and the inductor. Layout can also play a big role and these are unknowns making the question difficult to answer. Given that you have used it once with success I have to suggest that you have the means to fix it and anyone reading your question does not.

Comment: Much more data needed. What is Vin to 7805, What is target Iout total? What are inductor and diode and anything else.

Comment: Within your description, there is no reason to use a 7805 to reduce the voltage supplying to MC33063. The 7805 just serves to waste power and generate heat. Also, the MC33063 can probably be more efficient with a higher input voltage.

Comment: Load current is about 70-75 mA. I'm using 1N5819 diode and 100uH inductor, and 1uH inductor for the filter. I'm using the 7805 to reduce the input from 12V(from battery) to 5V

Answer (score 2):

This should be well within the ICs capability.
It worked for you previously.
This is a very standard and well tested circuit.
So:

You probably have a circuit error. 
If the 7805 is getting hot then either it is not well enough heat-sunk or there is an unintended extra load somewhere. This could be in the +5V circuitry OR the -9V circuitry.